# Записать данные с помощью javascript в поля на html страницу

Tags: javascript

Передаются данные с флэшки на html страницу, на этой странице форма. Как с помощью javascript поймать и вставить данные форму, чтобы потом передать их php файлу для отправки сообщения?

Comment: А посредством чего у вас флешка с сайтом связана? :)

Comment: Никак вообще. С флэхи гетом передадим данные, надо яваскриптом их поймать и в форму вставить. а потом уже передадим на отправку.

Comment: Запрос с get-ом в любом случае сразу идет на сервер. Там же и сгенерируйте заполненную форму. Или вы каким-то чудом решили обращаться к страничке гетом?

Comment: Отправим постом. Не принципиально, надо уловить это на в форму с флэхи. Разводим по этому поводу болтовню?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю, то у вас есть некий flash - объект, в котором есть форма с полями, и там-же есть кнопка "Отправить", при нажатии на которую происходит GET запрос некой html страницы, на которой javascript разбирает GET параметры из URL и заполняет соответствующую HTML форму.

Вот пример такого html файла:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function parseQueryStringAndFillForm (name) {
        var f = document.forms[name];

        if (f) {
            var vars = window.location.search.substring(1).split("&");

            for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
                var pair = vars[i].split("=");
                var field = f.elements[pair[0]];

                if (field) {
                    field.value = unescape(pair[1]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<form name="theForm">
    <label for="theForm-name">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="theForm-name" />
    </label>
    <br />
    <label for="theForm-email">
        Name: <input type="text" name="email" id="theForm-email" />
    </label>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    parseQueryStringAndFillForm("theForm");
</script>
```

Второй вариант более сложный - есть flash - объект, в нем есть форма в ней, в совою очеред кнопка "Отправить" при нажатии на которую посредством [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6) данные из flash формы передаются в html-форму. Если вас интересует именно этот вариант - то см. [примеры к ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf626ae-7fe8.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f31)

P.S.
В принципе javascript в прослойке между flash и php лишний, можно сразу в php обработать GET параметры которые переданы через flash

Comment: Спасибо большое. Вы все правильно поняли. :)

Comment: В первом варианте. Поля на флэше и на хтмл должны называться одинаково?

Comment: Я честно говоря не знаю как там во флеше с полями, нужно посмотреть что получается после GET запроса, но в примере подразумевается что да, но это можно легко исправить , там вместо

    var field = f.elements[pair[0]];
    if (field) {
        field.value = unescape(pair[1]);
    }

написать что-то типа:


   switch (pair[0]) {
      case "email":
         f.elements["mail"].value = unescape(pair[1]);
         break;
   }


И рассмотреть все сочетания входящих - исходящих полей.

Comment: Более - менее вменяемый код (не тестировал) см.: https://gist.github.com/1319414

Comment: Спасибо, буду тестить